# Is "zero-copy networking" implemented by default on Linux?

Tags: networking, kernel

I saw this article:

http://lwn.net/2001/0419/kernel.php3

> Zero-copy networking will be in 2.4.4. This patch, by David Miller,
>   Alexey Kuznetsov, and others, has been in development and testing for
>   some time, and was incorporated into the "ac" kernel series back in
>   2.4.2ac4. In a way, it is a surprising change to see in a stable kernel series, since it makes fundamental changes deep in the
>   networking code. From all reports, however, it is solid, and, in
>   certain situations, it should produce significant performance
>   benefits.

Can someone tell me if zero-copy networking exists by default in Linux, or whether this patch was just to allow people who wanted to do zero-copy networking to be able to implement it?

In other words, in the current Ubuntu does it perform zero-copy networking all the time or would I have to use certain system calls to utilise the above patch?

Comment: According to how I understand the article it will always perform zero-copy networking as long as the driver of your network card supports it. If not, it won't, but there is no way how you could dynamically enable/disable it.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux' kernel git repo:

`git log --oneline -- drivers/net | head -n5000 | egrep -i 'zero[[:space:]]*copy'`

tells us:

- 7d9e6dd macvtap: do not zerocopy if iov needs more pages than MAX_SKB_FRAGS
- 05464d2 tuntap: do not zerocopy if iov needs more pages than MAX_SKB_FRAGS
- bd31fdd macvtap: correctly linearize skb when zerocopy is used
- d09ec76 tuntap: correctly linearize skb when zerocopy is used
- 19a6afb tuntap: set SOCK_ZEROCOPY flag during open
- 149d36f tun: report orphan frags errors to zero copy callback

which (I believe) answers your question clearly and positive. ;)